# NeoVim Editing previous file if it's a directory fails

Tags: neovim

A workflow I often use in vim is to edit a directory. Then I find a file I am interested in, and open it with enter.

If I want to get back to the directory, in vim it's `:e #`

However, frequently in NeoVim I get the following error:

`E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"`

Is there something I can do to make this work in nvim? I like it, but this really is a key part of my workflow. Alternate mechanisms could work.

I also have a hard time understanding this error message.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/